# Does the creation and sale of custom action figures based on existing properties fall under the "fan merchandise" answers?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, business

I'm an avid action figure collector, and have dabbled in trying to make my own custom action figures through the years.

I've considered the ability to make some profit off of the process, but I wasn't sure if making and selling customs based on existing properties would get me into legal trouble.

I have seen many different customizer websites, and many of them ultimately sell their customs on eBay. These customs are based on properties from Marvel, Stat Wars, and anime; pretty much any existing property.

Would there be any legal ramifications to me starting an action figure business that took requests which may end up making figures based on existing properties then?

Thank you all for your time in advance

Edit to answer User65535's question.

My intent would be to design an action figure custom for my customer, which may be based on a character from a property like Marvel.

This custom would then be made with a "blank body" (companies sell blank figures fully intended for making customs with them), be painted by me, as well as have their outfits sculpted or made with cloth by me with patterns I create based on that character's outfit.

There are custimizers that will take existing figures, like Hasbro's Marvel Legends figures, and do similar sculpt and paint work to make new figures that way. I don't intend to do that for mine, but I would be curious on the legal ramifications of selling a figure like that too.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean create new items based on customers designs, which may be based on Marvel characters, and not take existing items (which were made under licence from Marvel) and customising them?

Comment: @User65535, thanks a ton for your response. I have provided an answer to your questions as an edit to my original question.